# Derangement Identity Proof

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

Use the following identity

$$ (-1)^k\frac{(n-k)}{k!} = (-1)^k\frac{n}{k!}+(-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}$$

to prove that $$Qn=D(n)+D(n-1)$$ (n=2,3,...)

D(n) is the number of derangements of an n-element set

I haven't had enough experience with combinatorics and proof writing to know whether to try to prove this recursively or use combinatorics or if there is another approach.

Comment: What is $Qn\;$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Does this mean that you know what $D(n)$ means?

Comment: @DKal: I presume that $D(n)$ is the number of derangements of an $n$-element set.

Answer (score 0):

$D_n$ is the number of derangements of the set $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ and $Q_n$ is the number of permutations from the set $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ where each permutation does not allow patterns of the form $(n-1)n$. By definition of $Q_n$ we know that $$Q_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose i}(-1)^i(n-i)!$$ which we can rewrite as $$Q_n=(n-1)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{(-1)^i(n-i)\over i!}.$$ This identity can be used to prove that $Q_n=D_n+D_{n-1}$. Also, we know that $$D_n=n!\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i{i\over i!}$$ and that $$D_{n-1}=(n-1)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{(-1)^i\over i!}.$$ So we could use these two sums to show that $D_n+D_{n-1}=Q_n$.